# Prevent static String from inlining in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, inline

Is there any way to prevent a static String property (or Java field) from inlining in Kotlin?

I have a case where I need to expose some value (just like a proxy library API) contained in an external library that is declared as a external dependency, that might change between its releases. Accessing directly this property results in inlining this value in my binaries, and that's what I want to avoid.

In Java the trick was to use some String manipulation methods like formatting, but they seem not to work in Kotlin.

Comment: I just tested this and it seems strings are inlined only if they are declared as `const val`. When I declared it as `val MY_VALUE = "FOO"` then I clearly see that the bytecode for consumer code invokes `getMy_VALUE()` function. Kotlin 1.5.0.

Comment: This is because `const val` are translated to Java's `static final` fields. Otherwise they are instance properties and hence cannot be inlined. What I need is how to reference a `const val`/`static final` fields in Kotlin code so that they won't get inlined.

Comment: Top-level `val MY_VALUE` property in `org.example.app.kt` will be compiled into `private final static MY_VALUE` field and `public final static getMY_VALUE()` method of autogenerated Java class named `org.example.AppKt`. If you put [`@JvmField` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) on it, getter won't be generated and the static field will have the same visibility as the property.

The same is applicable for properties of (companion) objects.

Inline on invocation site doesn't happen for such properties (Kotlin 1.5.20).